# Having trouble making a twisting animation more realistic

Tags: animation

I am new to animating in blender, and I have been using the curve modifier to create a specific looking circle, but I want to animate it to make it look like it twists from a circle to a figure eight. The problem is, I tried using shape keys with one as the original circle and one as the final figure eight, but then, of course, it just moves in a linear fashion from circle to figure eight, but this isn't realistic. When you take a rubber band and twist it to make a figure eight you don't move it linearly to the eight, you twist the band around. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? I've tried using intermediate shape keys, but it doesn't flow smoothly it abruptly stops at the intermediate step and continues. I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Use curves and animate the rotation of the the handles to affect the shape like a rubber band.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [animation of cylinder to figure eight](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194255/animation-of-proportional-editing-deformation-cylinder-to-figure-eight)

Comment: Can you provide some images of the base shape? Is it a mesh or a curve, how it is?

Comment: Sorry, I added  a 2d representation of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good place to model the band as a curve (with a rectangular curve *Bevel* object,) and use the shipped [*Animall*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/animation/animall.html) add-on, which enables you to key-frame control-points, and their tilt values.

This animation is of a default Curve > Circle, subdivided once. The three vertices at each end are rotated in opposite directions, while the entire circle rotates through 90 to present the figure-of-eight to the camera. *Animall* permits the keying of tilts, rotations, locations of the control-points to keep everything more or less in shape.

[image]

[image]

(v2.91 .blend file)

Answer (score -1):

Consider at least two options.

- Hook Modifier. Rotate along its axis with the appropriate point selection.
- Simple deform modifier with twist enabled as shown below.

[image]

In the image above are three stages of view.  Shape Keys and Hook Modifier.  With more care the viewer can remove some of the flaws.  You see a twist empty controller for twist of the bottom half and an organizing controller.

The below image is a quick approximation to the question.  Perhaps a better approximation will come.  At the moment you are seeing a view convenient for this candidate answer.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I was thinking about using armature, but I'm not sure how to use it for a curve, could you please tell me how I could use it in this situation?